# CXF endpoint definition, and Failed to resolve endpoint:No bean could be found in the registry

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I try to define a CXF endpoint, but the it doesn't work.
When I want to address the endpoint then I'v got the "bean not found" exception.

CXF definition:

```
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {

        errorHandler(deadLetterChannel(systemInfo.getQueuName())
                .allowRedeliveryWhileStopping(true)
                .maximumRedeliveries(-1)
                );

        onException(Exception.class).process(routeHandlingBean);


        CamelContext camelContext = getContext();

        CxfEndpoint partnerTestService = new CxfEndpoint();
        partnerTestService.setEndpointNameString("partnerTestService");
        partnerTestService.setAddress("http://localhost:9081/MockPartnerService");
        partnerTestService.setWsdlURL("http://localhost:9081/MockPartnerService?wsdl");
        partnerTestService.setServiceClass(aaa.bbb.ccc.service.PartnerService.class);
        partnerTestService.setServiceNameString("partnerTestService");
        partnerTestService.setDataFormat(DataFormat.CXF_MESSAGE);
        partnerTestService.setCamelContext(camelContext);

        try {
            camelContext.addEndpoint("partnerTestService", partnerTestService);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I try to call the endpoint:

```
cxf:bean:partnerTestService
```

Then I have got this error message:

```
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:partnerTestService due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: partnerTestService of type: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint
```

I don't know what else I have to set up.

Thx!
Feri

Comment: You have included the apache CXF dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I did it. The project contains some other routes, what routes use the CXF-type endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the usage of CxfEndpoint class. I wrote a function what gives back a needed object (instead of string endpoint), and so it is work.

The route definition:

```
    ValueBuilder dynRouterMethod = method(esbDynRouter, "endpointRoute");

    from(queueName).id(systemInfo.getRouteId()).routeId(systemInfo.getRouteId()).autoStartup(false)
    .transacted()
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, systemInfo.getRouteId() + " route usage.")
    .beanRef("statusUpdaterBean", "updateSendingStatus")
    .dynamicRouter(dynRouterMethod)
    .beanRef("statusUpdaterBean", "updateSentStatus")
    ;
```

The procedure (it called in dynamic router procedure):

```
private CxfEndpoint getCxfEndpoint(DispConfView target) throws Exception
    {
        CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = (CxfEndpoint) camelContext.getEndpoint(<Something>);

        if (cxfEndpoint == null)
        {
            String serviceClassNme = <class name what represent the POJO class>;
            String methodName = <WS methode name>;

            cxfEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
            cxfEndpoint.setAddress(methodName);
            cxfEndpoint.setDataFormat(DataFormat.POJO);
            cxfEndpoint.setServiceClass(serviceClassNme);

            cxfEndpoint.setCamelContext(camelContext);

            camelContext.addEndpoint(<Something>, cxfEndpoint);
        }

        return cxfEndpoint;
    }
```

This solution work if the message is POJO-type.